# How to link sub-forms inside a form in Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I would like to create a sub-form in which there are links to another table inside the fields of a column. This is pretty much as it is in the Northwind Database sample of Access, in where in the 'Home' form there are two tables and, in the product table, there are links to the product details.

My question is how to create those links first, and how can I make my forms to 'pop-up' in smaller windows as there is in this example?

I will appreciate a lot the help, thank you very much in advance.

Jim.

Edit with images:

[image]

The main page of the Northwind database looks like this. My concern is about the links on 'Products', that their show information of the selected product. When you click on the desired product, it opens a form with the information about the product but in a new window, like this:

[image]

Here there is the form when you click on the name. I'm looking into the tables and subforms of the database but I can't find clues about how was this done. Meanwhile I'm reading various tutorials of Access but for the moment there's no success on that. Hope it's clear what I'm trying to show. Anyone has any clue about how can this be done? Thank you very much.

Edit 2: I've solved the pop-up window for the forms, so I can manage to do this. Now I'm struggling on finding how to link those fields of a table with other forms. The hyperlink doesn't seem to allow me to do it. Any clues? Thank you

Comment: This is a very broad question and involves too many details to be an effective question on Stack Overflow.  I suggest searching for MS Access tutorials online.  It sounds like you already have a good example.  It will take time and work to learn the details, but all such details can't be laid out here.  Best regards!  Or, you could edit your question with more specifics, including details of what you have tried thus far.

Comment: If you have the Northwind database as example, can't you replicate the structure? It's called 'reverse engineering'. I am not quite sure what you are asking for, but is it like: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: Hello, and thank you both for your comments, I appreciate them. I've edited the question post with two images and a bit more clues about what I want to do. Hope it is clear and someone can give a clue about it. Thank you

Comment: I've edited the first post again, where the only issue by now is the links in the products table.

Comment: Open the subform in design view, and you'll see that the textboxes have embedded macros (yikes) for `OnClick`.